# How to "slipstream" Acrobat 10.1.1 into Acrobat 10 install point?

Tags: adobe, adobe-acrobat

I want to roll out Acrobat 10.1.1. So, I want to "slipstream" 10.1.1 into my install point. I do not want to roll out 10 and then roll out 10.1.1 update. Any clues on how I can do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can download a standalone installation of 10.1.1 here:
http://get.adobe.com/reader/enterprise/

If you choose to slipstream an existing installation, try this:

This is what I've got documented for past versions. I'm not sure how much it has changed in 10.0.

First, make sure you have an extracted installation of 10:

```
%UserProfile%\Desktop\adobereaderX.exe -nos_o"C:\readerx" -nos_ne
cd C:\readerx
msiexec /a AcroRead.msi
```

Now you should have a folder that contains an extracted installation.

Then download the .msp file from here:
http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Windows

Then I've used the following command:

```
msiexec /a AcroRead.msi /p patchname.msp
```

To put it into a previously extracted full install of Reader.

The commands should be either the same or similar for version 10. I've got to update my own deployment, so I'll update this answer with any changes if I find they're needed.

Answer (score 2):

You make an Administrative Install Point using the `/a` option on the MSI file. Then, you use the `/p` or `/patch` option to patch the AIP with the .1 patch. You can then deploy it from there via MSI, logon script, SCCM, or whatever else. This is *the* official way to patch any MSI where the vendor releases .msp files as patches.